# convert AVPicture to array<unsigned char>

Tags: arrays, ffmpeg, c++-cli

I use ffmpeg to extract frame of video in c++. I want to get `array<unsigned char>` of frame in c++ but I get `AVFrame` from this line code.

```
avcodec_decode_video2(codecContext, DecodedFrame, &gotPicture, Packet);
```

So I use `sws_scale` to convert `AVFrame` to `AVPicture` but also I cannot got `array<unsigned char>` from frame.

```
sws_scale(convertContext, DecodedFrame->data, DecodedFrame->linesize, 0, (codecContext)->height, convertedFrame->data, convertedFrame->linesize);
```

So can anyone help me to convert `AVFrame` or `AVPicture` to `array<unsigned char>`?

Comment: The decoded frame is usually YUV and the image is stored in AVFrame.data[0-2] as planar. This will be different for RGB conversion after using swscale, but still the pixel data in AVFrame.data[]. The AVFrame.linesize[] will usually be different from the width so remember that.

Answer (score 1):

`AVPicture` is deprecated. Converting to it is meaningless since `AVFrame` is its alternative.

If I understand this question correctly, you're trying to get the raw picture pixels value to a `std::array`. If such so, just dump the [data](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/structAVFrame.html#a1d0f65014a8d1bf78cec8cbed2304992) fields of `AVFrame` into it.

```
avcodec_decode_video2(codecContext, DecodedFrame, &gotPicture, Packet);

// If you need rgb, create a swscontext to convert from video pixel format
sws_ctx = sws_getContext(DecodedFrame->width, DecodedFrame->height, codecContext->pix_fmt, DecodedFrame->width, DecodedFrame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, 0, 0, 0, 0);

uint8_t* rgb_data[4];  int rgb_linesize[4];
av_image_alloc(rgb_data, rgb_linesize, DecodedFrame->width, DecodedFrame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, 32); 
sws_scale(sws_ctx, DecodedFrame->data, DecodedFrame->linesize, 0, DecodedFrame->height, rgb_data, rgb_linesize);

// RGB24 is a packed format. It means there is only one plane and all data in it. 
size_t rgb_size = DecodedFrame->width * DecodedFrame->height * 3;
std::array<uint8_t, rgb_size> rgb_arr;
std::copy_n(rgb_data[0], rgb_size, rgb_arr);
```

Comment: Nontype template arguments have to be constexpr.  Check the question tags, it isn't std array.